# Is it a Spring `Dalston` bug?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

If I use `Brixton.RELEASE` my `client_credentials` grant type works fine but as soon as I change this to `Dalston.SR2` or `Dalston.SR3`, it starts failing with following stack trace:

```
2017-08-29 19:56:51.017 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8793-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/email] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException: status 403 reading AuthServiceClient#test(String); content:
email-service_1   | {"timestamp":1504036611014,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/auth/users/testPermissions/user-name"}] with root cause
email-service_1   | 
email-service_1   | feign.FeignException: status 403 reading AuthServiceClient#test(String); content:
email-service_1   | {"timestamp":1504036611014,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/auth/users/testPermissions/user-name"}
email-service_1   |     at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.test(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
email-service_1   |     at com.vtb.email.controller.EmailController.test(EmailController.java:45) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
email-service_1   |     at com.vtb.email.controller.EmailController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dfa6170f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at com.vtb.email.controller.EmailController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd6b4623.test(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
email-service_1   |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
email-service_1   |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
email-service_1   |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
email-service_1   |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
email-service_1   |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
email-service_1   |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]
email-service_1   |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Can anybody tell what might be wrong here?